# Ionic FacebookConnectPlugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to implement Facebook login in my ionic application. But when the user try to login to via Facebook at first, it says "Invalid hash key." following as below.[image]
After this, I've check the hash key that was added on Facebook developer site. But the keys that displayed on app and written in Facebook developer sites are same following as below:
[image]
Also, the strange thing is after this happened, when I tried to login again with facebook developer account, it works. But also after this, the try to login with normal facebook account, it doesn't work. What's wrong and why this happens?
The implemented codes are here:

```
$scope.fblogin = function(){
    var fbLoginParams = ['public_profile','email'];
    $ionicLoading.show({template: '<ion-spinner icon="lines" class="spinner-calm"></ion-spinner><p>Getting Facebook Login Status...</p>'});
    facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(
        function(response)  //Already Facebook Logined
        {
            //Get My Profile From Facebook
            if (response.status == "connected")
            {                    
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $state.go('main.home');
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(response);
                //Prepare For Facebook Login
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $ionicLoading.show({template: '<ion-spinner icon="lines" class="spinner-calm"></ion-spinner><p>Logging in Facebook...</p>'});

                facebookConnectPlugin.login(fbLoginParams,
                    function(response)
                    {
                        $ionicLoading.hide();                            
                        $state.go('main.home');
                    },
                    function (response)
                    {
                        //Facebook Login Failed.
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                        alert('Failed to login Facebook');
                    }
                );
            }
        },
        function(response) // Not Logined
        {
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: what are you entering in developer site after Z and v

Comment: Two keys are same. Why this happens?

Comment: did you copied it as sometime I had got the same error because of small letter 'L' and capital 'i'

Comment: I've copied the key displayed on app from logcat and paste it to the developer site.